# How to merge rows of one table to another while keeping foreign key constraints on autogenerated columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are two tables that I have, with `Table B` referencing `Table A`:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    [Id_A] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ... 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA_Id_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id_A] ASC
    )
)

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
    [Id_B] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RefId_A] [bigint] NOT NULL
    ... 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableB_Id_B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id_B] ASC
    )
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableB]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Id_A] FOREIGN KEY([RefId_A])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TableA] ([Id_A])
```

These two tables are part of 2 databases.

- `Table A` and `Table B` in database 1;
- `Table A` and `Table B` in database 2.

I need to merge the rows of `Table A` from database 1 into `Table A` of database 2 and the rows of `Table B` from database 1 into `Table B` of database 2.

I used the `SQL Data  Import and Export Wizard` , checked the `Enable Identity Insert` option but it fails:

> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint 'PK_TableB_Id_B'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.TableB'. The duplicate key value is (1).".  (SQL Server Import and
>   Export Wizard)

Which seems to make sense. There are rows in `Table B` of database 1 that have the same auto-generated PK as rows of `Table B` in database 2.

**QUESTION**

In this scenario, how can I merge the tables content from database 1 to the tables of database 2 *while maintaining the foreign key constraints*?

Comment: Use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTable ON` and you can explicitly insert new identity values overriding the identity property. Then use the `INSERT INTO ... OUTPUT` or `MERGE... OUTPUT` clause to obtain the relationship between the previous database identity value to the new one, and use this relationship to insert the other table's foreign key values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the following. In here we assume that you need to insert all records as new ones (and not compare if some already exist or not). I wrapped both operations in a transaction to ensure that both go OK or none at all.

```
BEGIN TRY

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#IdentityRelationships') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #IdentityRelationships

    CREATE TABLE #IdentityRelationships (
        OldIdentity INT,
        NewIdentity INT)

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        ;WITH SourceData AS
        (
            SELECT
                OldIdentity = A.Id_A,
                OtherColumn = A.OtherColumn
            FROM
                Database1.Schema.TableA AS A
        )
        MERGE INTO 
            Database2.Schema.TableA AS T
        USING
            SourceData AS S ON 1 = 0 -- Will always execute the "WHEN NOT MATCHED" operation 
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (
                OtherColumn)
            VALUES (
                S.OtherColumn)
            OUTPUT
                inserted.Id_A, -- "MERGE" clause can output non-inserted values
                S.ID_A
            INTO
                #IdentityRelationships (
                    NewIdentity,
                    OldIdentity);

        INSERT INTO Database2.Schema.TableB (
            RefId_A,
            OtherData)
        SELECT
            RefId_A = I.NewIdentity,
            OtherData = T.OtherData
        FROM
            Database1.Schema.TableB AS T
            INNER JOIN #IdentityRelationships AS I ON T.RefID_A = I.OldIdentity

    COMMIT

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE @v_ErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ERROR_MESSAGE())

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK

    RAISERROR (@v_ErrorMessage, 16, 1)

END CATCH
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

There is no simple way to do this.  Your primary keys are identity columns that both start at "1", so the relationships are ambiguous.

You have two options:

1. A composite primary key, identifying the database source of the records.
2. A new primary key.  You *can* preserve the existing primary key values from one database.

Your question doesn't provide enough information to say which is the better approach:  "merge" is not clearly defined.

I might suggest that you just recreate all the tables.  Insert all the rows from table A into a new table.  Add a *new* identity primary key.  Keep the original primary key and source.

Then bring the data from Table B into a new table, looking up the new primary key in the new Table A.  At this point, the new Table B is finished, except for defining the primary key constraint.

Then drop the unnecessarily columns in the new table A.

Comment: By "Merge", I mean taking the rows of the source tables in database 1 and coping them into the tables of database 2.